# Event " Button Click" not Working C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to make a program With Two buttons Start and Stop. Here is the code:

```
namespace rcToOnBoardPC
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        Communication objCommunication = new Communication();
        DataTable A = new DataTable();
        public int a; 

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { 
           objCommunication.intialiseCAN();
           a = 1;
           A = Data.GetAccessDataTable("TestData", "testDB.accdb");
           this.dataGridView1.DataSource = A;
           objCommunication.ID0008Update10ms(A,a);// Runs Infinte While if a=1         
        }

       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            a = 0;
            string timeEnd = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            objCommunication.unIntialiseCAN();      
            Environment.Exit(1);    
        }

        public void textBox1Update(string message)
        {
            textBox1.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I face is that after "button1_click" a is set as 1 and if a=1 then method "ID0008Update10ms" runs an infinite while. If i try to generate "button2_Click" I am not able to achieve it, or it doesnt work at all so a is never set to zero. **Why is this issue?**

Comment: in designer double click on button and see where it takes the cursor.

Comment: Perhaps its your infinite loop blocking everything else. Try to do long tasks in the background in a separate thread, perhaps using BackgroundWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If button1_Click is running an infinite loop, it will block the UI thread.

This means that any other events on the UI thread cannot be processed, including button2_Click.

Comment: I understand this, shall i run a parallel task to accept button2_Click and pass the value to my method ID0008Update10ms. (some suggest BackgroundWorker)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the infinite while on a background thread or to implement it with a thread.sleep of 1 ms.
The issue maybe that you're blocking the UI thread that cannot handle the secondo click on the button 2

Comment: For test purposes you can give it a try with Thread.Sleep() but it shouldn't be used productive. Rather implement a background thread. @OP